# Нажатие элементов меню

Tags: android, xml, меню

Имеется код:

MainActivity.java:

```
package asus.example.com.fitnessapp;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    final TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.textView);
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.nav_items,menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){
        switch (item.getItemId()){
            case R.id.home:
                textView.setText("Home");
                return true;
            case R.id.notification:
                textView.setText("Notification");
                return true;
            case R.id.profile:
                textView.setText("Profile");
                return true;
                default:
                    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="52dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/nav_items"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textView"/>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

nav_items.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/home"
        android:title="@string/home"
        android:icon="@drawable/home" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/notification"
        android:title="@string/notifications"
        android:icon="@drawable/notification" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/profile"
        android:icon="@drawable/person"
        android:title="@string/profile" />
</menu>
```

**UPDATE**

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="asus.example.com.fitnessapp">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

При выполнении выдает ошибку:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity
>   ComponentInfo{asus.example.com.fitnessapp/asus.example.com.fitnessapp.MainActivity}:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
>   'android.view.Window$Callback android.view.Window.getCallback()' on a
>   null object reference
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2843)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3048)
>           at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
>           at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
>           at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1808)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
>        Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.Window$Callback
>   android.view.Window.getCallback()' on a null object reference
>           at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:249)
>           at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(AppCompatDelegate.java:182)
>           at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.getDelegate(AppCompatActivity.java:520)
>           at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.findViewById(AppCompatActivity.java:191)
>           at asus.example.com.fitnessapp.MainActivity.(MainActivity.java:11)
>           at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method)
>           at android.app.AppComponentFactory.instantiateActivity(AppComponentFactory.java:69)
>           at android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory.instantiateActivity(CoreComponentFactory.java:43)
>           at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1215)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2831)

В чем проблема и как решить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Получай ссылку на представление в методе `onCreate`

```
final TextView textView;

@Override 
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState { 
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    textView = findViewById(R.id.textView);
 }
```

Comment: Не помогает. У Вас как минимум ошибка в том, что final не проинициализировано. Да и какая разница, где получать ссылку в методе или глобально в классе?

Comment: Тогда покажите код манифеста

Comment: Добавил манифест

Comment: Хм, вроде в коде все в порядке, замените final на private, из кода причина могла быть по всей видимости только в попытке инициализировать вью до инициализации разметки. Если замена final>private не поможет, попробуйте отключить InstantRun и также сделайте Build>Rebuild & Clean

Comment: Да, видимо это какой-то лаг в студии. После Clean все нормально запустилось. Только почему-то на нажатия меню не реагирует. По логике в textview должен текст добавляться, но на деле нет

Comment: Это лучше уже отдельным вопросом

Answer (score 2):

[документация](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#findViewById(int))

Там написанно что findViewById после onCreate() активити нужно вызывать.

```
private TextView textView;

@Override 
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState { 
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    textView = findViewById(R.id.textView);
 }
```